# The "two-state solution" for Israel in Orthodox Judaism

Tags: politics-government, state-of-israel, public-policy

There is a commonly cited machloket between Chabad and many other chassidim (particularly Satmar) in regards to the validity of the State of Israel. There are also a panoply of views among non-chassidim, however if asked, I would be hard-put to find a source for them.

Do any notable rabbanim take a middle road and support a [two-state solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-state_solution) between The State of Israel (not the land) and the Palestinians? If so, what is their halachic basis?

Comment: In other words, answers based merely on politics are out of scope. An ideal answer would give a rav who supports a two-state solution from a halachic perspective.

Answer (score 5):

Rav Ovadia Yosef originally supported the Oslo Accords due to pikuach nefesh - Rabin and his generals told him it would save lives. Later on after seeing the results - over 3000 Jews murdered and thousands more maimed - he changed his position.